# Problems using DecimalFormat

Tags: java, decimalformat

I am having problems using `DecimalFormat` when I am going to print out coefficients after a regression.

Here is the part of the code that is facing problems;

```
DecimalFormat twoDForm = new DecimalFormat("0.00");   
private double s(double d){  
    return Double.valueOf(twoDForm.format(d));  
}
```

and here is the error message in eclipse;

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "0,16"  
 at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(Unknown Source)  
 at java.lang.Double.valueOf(Unknown Source)  
 at model.ARF2.s(ARF2.java:126)  
 at model.ARF2.printBestModel(ARF2.java:114)  
 at testing.testclass3.bestForecastingModel(testclass3.java:69)  
 at testing.testclass3.main(testclass3.java:36)
```

Please let me know if anyone has any surgestions on how to fix the code. I want two decimals on my coefficients.

Thank you

Lars

Comment: Is the dot correct? Shouldn't it be `DecimalFormat twoDForm = new DecimalFormat("0,00");`? I do not remember right now.

Comment: what is the input into the method `s`?

Comment: The code is all wrong, but the correct answer depends on what you want to do.  Do you want to print just two decimal places, truncating the rest (effectively rounding down)?  Or do you want to use a specific method for rounding that you want to use when there are more digits than you have decimal places for printing?

Answer (score 19):

use:

```
    DecimalFormat twoDForm = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
    DecimalFormatSymbols dfs = new DecimalFormatSymbols();
    dfs.setDecimalSeparator('.');
    twoDForm.setDecimalFormatSymbols(dfs);
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Its perfect!! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html

The following excerpt appears to be part of your problem:

> To obtain a NumberFormat for a
>   specific locale, including the default
>   locale, call one of NumberFormat's
>   factory methods, such as
>   getInstance(). In general, do not call
>   the DecimalFormat constructors
>   directly, since the NumberFormat
>   factory methods may return subclasses
>   other than DecimalFormat. If you need
>   to customize the format object, do
>   something like this:

```
 NumberFormat f = NumberFormat.getInstance(loc);
 if (f instanceof DecimalFormat) {
     ((DecimalFormat) f).setDecimalSeparatorAlwaysShown(true);
 }
```

You may want to use the applyPattern method:

> applyPattern
>
> public void applyPattern(String
>   pattern) Apply the given pattern to
>   this Format object. A pattern is a
>   short-hand specification for the
>   various formatting properties. These
>   properties can also be changed
>   individually through the various
>   setter methods. There is no limit to
>   integer digits are set by this
>   routine, since that is the typical
>   end-user desire; use setMaximumInteger
>   if you want to set a real value. For
>   negative numbers, use a second
>   pattern, separated by a semicolon
>
> Example "#,#00.0#" -> 1,234.56
>
> This means a minimum of 2 integer
>   digits, 1 fraction digit, and a
>   maximum of 2 fraction digits.
>
> Example: "#,#00.0#;(#,#00.0#)" for
>   negatives in parentheses.
>
> In negative patterns, the minimum and
>   maximum counts are ignored; these are
>   presumed to be set in the positive
>   pattern.
>
> Throws: NullPointerException - if
>   pattern is null
>   IllegalArgumentException - if the
>   given pattern is invalid.

Answer (score 2):

You are encountering an i18n issue. `DecimalFormat` is using your default locale which specifies the decimal separator as <kbd>,</kbd>. However, the `Double.valueOf` does not use the locale. It always expects that the decimal separator is <kbd>.</kbd>.

If you want to parse a string formatted with `DecimalFormat` then you need to use [DecimalFormat.parse](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html#parse%28java.lang.String,%20java.text.ParsePosition%29)

Answer (score 1):

I think what you intended to do is:

```
private static String s(double d) {
   return twoDForm.format(d);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to format the number? Or round it? If you're formatting it, shouldn't your "s" method (bad name IMO, btw, but it's private, so it's your call) return a `java.lang.String` instead of a `double`?

Answer (score 0):

Check your Locale.

```
DecimalFormat twoDForm = new DecimalFormat("0.00");   
    private double s(double d){ 

    String doubleString =  displayNumberAmount(twoDForm.format(d));
        return Double.valueOf(doubleString);  
    } 

    public static String displayNumberAmount(String amount) {

            NumberFormat numberFormat = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.CANADA_FRENCH);

            Number number = 0;

            try {
                number = numberFormat.parse(amount);

            } catch (ParseException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return String.format(Locale.US, "%1$,.2f", number);
        }
```