# Applet java throws exception with chrome

Tags: java, google-chrome, exception, japplet, invocationtargetexception

I'm developing a Django site with an applet Java.

Some days ago the applet start to fail loading in my chrome browser. I was still in developing and I tought that was a cache problem, so to test I started to use firefox.

At today the applet is developed at 90%, and on firefox works smoothy. No problems at all.

So I was working on some JS and I opened chrome (like its debugger), so I cleaned the chrome's cache folder and the java plugin cache, and I open the site.

The applet failed to load. Here is the error:

```
 java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
     at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
     at sun.applet.PluginAppletSecurityContext$5.run(PluginAppletSecurityContext.java:943)
     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
     at sun.applet.PluginAppletSecurityContext.handleMessage(PluginAppletSecurityContext.java:940)
     at sun.applet.AppletSecurityContextManager.handleMessage(AppletSecurityContextManager.java:70)
     at sun.applet.PluginStreamHandler.handleMessage(PluginStreamHandler.java:235)
     at sun.applet.PluginMessageHandlerWorker.run(PluginMessageHandlerWorker.java:78)
 Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "0,000000"
     at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1241)
     at java.lang.Double.valueOf(Double.java:504)
     at java.lang.Double.<init>(Double.java:597)
     ... 10 more
 java.lang.NullPointerException
     at sun.applet.PluginAppletViewer.getMember(PluginAppletViewer.java:1020)
     at netscape.javascript.JSObject.getMember(JSObject.java:155)
     at objects.CommunicationWithJS.parseFloors(CommunicationWithJS.java:75)
     at main.MapGenerator.start(MapGenerator.java:27)
     at sun.applet.AppletPanel.run(AppletPanel.java:476)
     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

The strange thing is that on Firefox works with no problems...

On loading, the applet calls some JS on the page to load a Json from the site.
This Json is than passed to the applet.

The communication between the applet and the page is managed by the **netscape** library.

The JS that loads the JSON:

```
    function getFloors() {
            var xmlHttp = null;

            xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xmlHttp.open( "GET", GET_FLOORS, false );
            xmlHttp.send(null);
            var json = JSON.parse(xmlHttp.responseText);

            return json;
    }
```

And the code on the applet:

```
public Floor[] parseFloors(URL codebase) {

    JSObject jsonFloors = (JSObject) window.eval(GET_FLOORS);

            // counter of the number of objects
    int i=0;
    for (; i < 50; i++) 
        try {
            if (jsonFloors.getSlot(i) == null)
                break;
        } catch (JSException jse) {
            break;
        }

    Floor[] floors = new Floor[i];

    for (int t=0; t < i; t++) {

        JSObject jsonFloor = (JSObject) jsonFloors.getSlot(t);
        try {
            int numero_di_piano = Integer.parseInt(jsonFloor.getMember(NUMERO_DI_PIANO)+"");
            URL link = new URL(codebase, jsonFloor.getMember(LINK).toString());
            float bearing = Float.parseFloat(jsonFloor.getMember(BEARING).toString());
            int id = Integer.parseInt(jsonFloor.getMember(ID).toString());

            Floor floor = new Floor(numero_di_piano, link, bearing, id);
            floors[t] = floor;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }   
    }
    return floors;
}
```

The error *CommunicationWithJS.java:75* is in

```
   int numero_di_piano = Integer.parseInt(jsonFloor.getMember(NUMERO_DI_PIANO)+"");
```

The value *NUMERO_DI_PIANO* returned from the server is an integer, I don't understand this strange behaviour.

**EDIT:**

I cross-tested the japplet with firefox and chrome, using some *println*.
It comes out that the exception shows up only when I try to extract from the Json an **int** value.
I succesfully extracted a double and a string.

On firefox the applet still working...
On chrome 0 becames "0,000000" and 4 becomes "4,000000".

**ADDITION**

I solved the problem forcing the server to convert the integers in strings. 
But I don't think it's the correct way to work, it's a workaround.
So, if somebody can come out with a valid answer, I will assign the points.

Comment: I found out that this behaviour exists only when trying to pass more than one parameter at the same time. I have a JS in the page that calls a JAVA method passing only one integer, and it works with no problems.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a complete answer, but based on the error you are getting and the similar issue we're running into loading the website detailed in http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=647706 I believe the issue is related to the system locale. Is the system locale something different from en_US?

For a reason I haven't yet been able to understand, when running Java inside Firefox the locale does not influence the formatting methods, but on Chrome/Chromium it does, which leads to it generating locale-formatted floats ("0,0" instead of "0.0" in the Brazilian pt_BR locale, for instance) which Java can then not parse properly (presumably using a locale-independent conversion).

See also [Problems using DecimalFormat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3735630/problems-using-decimalformat)