# Save float number sqlite error rounding

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm saving float data in sqlite trough in my aplicaton. The problem is that when I saving the value 99999.99 the sqlite is rounding it to 100000.00. And the same is happening when i try to save 999999.99, its rounding it to 1000000.00. What is happening? The problem is in the Table "custo".

```
public static final String fghs_CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " +
   asdfgasfdg + " (" +      
    cust + " double, " +
```

Comment: Which data type is using for that?

Comment: What code are you using to store/retrieve column data?

Answer (score 0):

it seems your sqlite table's column type is integer. If so then use REAL as the data type.

Comment: He is using a DOUBLE, which is the same as REAL.

Answer (score 0):

You should change the float variable in java to a double, which has a higher precision. The following [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9044728/android-sqlite-saving-retrieving-data-of-type-real) explains the problem.

As pointed out in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10153901/2910492), the following is a nice example of float precision:

```
float f = 22.2;
printf("The number is: %.9f\n", f);<>
```

The output is:

```
22.200000763
```

Comment: I changed to double and it steel rounding.

Comment: Please show the code you use to create the database table, and the cod e you use to insert into the database.

Comment: the code is here. I tryed wit decimal, with double and its rounding yet.

Comment: Can you also show the java code where you insert en retrieve data from the database?